# Custom dialog takes time to show up

Tags: android, performance, dialog, customdialog

When I implement a custom dialog by using AlertDialog.Builder or DialogFragment which has a fairly complex layout (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLVaL.png) one) the dialog takes time to show up. But when the dialog just contains a couple of editText or so... there is no issue in showing up of the dialog. Why is it so?

Is it that the AlertDialog framework is used to build dialogs that are used just to alert the users? (as the name implies.)

Are there some other frameworks that can be used to implement complex custom dialogs?

I have tried the following things to fix the issue:

1. Attempted to implement threading so that my dialog is ready in a background
   thread and show it when I want. But this is not allowed in general
   as any other thread except UI thread aren't supposed to touch UI
   related events.
2. Made the dialog a global variable, initialized it in onCreate and
   then show the dialog onButtonClick.
3. Switched to CONSTRAINT LAYOUT
4. Used an activity as a dialog by setting the dialog theme to the
   activity in the manifest file.

I am extending to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63297031/dialog-pops-up-very-slow) question.
Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The layout is quite simple, it shouldn't be an issue.
Do you have any logic to populate those spinners? Maybe share your xml

Comment: @MaiconHellmann thanks for responding please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63297031/dialog-pops-up-very-slow) question of mine.

Comment: I have used ArrayAdapter (ArrayLists being fed into it) to populate the spinners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog) and [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment) frameworks are slow because they need to some time to do calculations and fragment stuffs. So a solution to this problem is, using the Dialog framework straight away.

1. Use the [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog) framework's constructor to initialize a Dialog object like this:

   ```
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog);
   // the second parameter is not compulsory and you can use other themes as well
   ```
2. Define the layout and then use `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.name_of_layout)`.
3. Use `dialog.findViewById(R.id.name_of_view)` to reference views from the dialog's layout file

And then implement the logic just like anyone would do in an activity class. Find out the best implementation for your use case by reading the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog).